# For what i can use redux in my app (advices)?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing a Weather App Fullstack application with React and Express. I want to add redux to my app but most of u gonna think it's worthless but I just want to that for training purpose. So in my app, I have signed up and login functions, I have auth with jwt so i send a jwt token from express to the client ( so maybe in here I can use redux or no), in the main page I have a field to type any city to get info about weather. So where I can use redux in that type of app?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use redux for global state that's shared by many components. Also, use thunks to manage your rest api requests

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current logged in user details in the redux store and then ultimately in local storage. For example, there would be components in your app which would render data based on if the user is logged in or not, you can store that info in your store and retrieve it from there. That's just a small example. You might want to show the logged in user's name in your app. You can store and retrieve that data from the redux store as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally It's totally depends on you. First you have to understand you application data and flow. If your application requires huge amount of data manipulation then I recommend you to use Redux it provides you single source of truth. React data flow from parent to children components.In large application data flows from multiple components via props and state so it's hard to track when data change. Redux provide you a store seperate from your components. So if comp A make changes in data that also used by comp B then comp B will get updated data. I hope that's make sence for you.